# Combining the Results of SQLAlchemy JOINs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, left-join

When you do something like,

```
session.query(BaseModel, JoinModel).join(JoinModel, BaseModel.id == JoinModel.id), isouter=True)
```

The result is is similar to the following,

```
(<__main__.BaseModel object at 0x000001E32BC81220>, <__main__.JoinModel object at 0x000001E32A15BE50>)
(<__main__.BaseModel object at 0x000001E32BC81220>, <__main__.JoinModel object at 0x000001E32A15BC70>)
(<__main__.BaseModel object at 0x000001E32BC81220>, <__main__.JoinModel object at 0x000001E32A317670>)
```

When you do `.__dict__` on one of these objects (either `BaseModel` or `JoinModel`) you can get the values of the attributes.

Is there an efficient way to combine the attributes of both these objects for one result? I mean in the end, ideally it should be just one set of values, right?

Comment: You can define relationships and backrefs in your model. This will help you to access the attributes without using join. 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html

Comment: This is great! You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [relationships and backrefs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html) in your model. This will help you to access the attributes without using join. Here is a sample code which might help you

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship

    class BaseModel():
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        join_model = relationship(
        "JoinModel",
        backref=backref("base_model", cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy=True))


    class JoinModel():
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        base_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("base.id",ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
        name = Column(String)
```

You can do like

```
base_model = BaseModel.query.all()

print(base_model.join_model.name)
```